# rich:comboBox button location

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

How can i control the location of the dropdown button of rich:combobox?
By default it's located on the right of the text element. I want it to be located on the left side of the text element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the official documentation to see which style class names are available for customizing the `<rich:combobox>`  http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_comboBox.html.

I try with this setting and the drop down button is located on the left hand side now:

```
  <rich:comboBox>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="suggestion 1"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="suggestion 2"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="suggestion 3"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="suggestion 4"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="suggestion 5"/>
    </rich:comboBox>
```

and declare this style in the page:

```
<style type="text/css">
input.rich-combobox-button, input.rich-combobox-button-inactive, input.rich-combobox-button-disabled{
       left:0px;
}

.rich-combobox-input, .rich-combobox-input-disabled, .rich-combobox-input-inactive{
font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
}   
</style>
```

[image]